# open a form in window pop-up using laravel5

Tags: popup, laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5 , so i am in a learning phase . I have search it on Google but I found nothing . So I need your help . My problem is that I have a form in \resources\views in the name of register.blade.php 
So I want to open this form on a window pop-up . What code should i in my controller and routes.php  so that it will open a my form in window pop-up

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support pop up functionality. Use javascript instead.

Have the form in your register.blade.php, and use a javascript plugin like [Popup.js](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/demos/) to show the view in a pop up box when the right event happens.